# Using multiple browser profiles in the same chromium app instance using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, automation, bots, puppeteer, chromium

I'd like to use multiple chromium profiles simultaneously using puppeteer. Doing it manually I'd add another profile having an instance of chromium running. This would cause chromium to create new processes:

[image: 5 simultaneous profiles created manually]

Trying to open new profiles using puppeteer, chromium creates separate app instances:

[image: p]

This results in significantly larger resource usage (mostly CPU). Having browser launched via puppeteer I am able to add new profiles manually and in such case behavior is the same as when not using puppeteer at all- new processes are added to existing app.

**Question:**

How to recreate this manual browser behavior using puppeteer? In other words, how to launch browser using puppeteer and then add profiles attached to the same app in OS via puppeteer?

**Current code:**

```
async function browserRun(){
  return await puppeteer.launch({ 
    args...
  ]})
   .then(async browser => {
      browser actions ...
  })
```

```
(async () => {
  await Promise.all([
    browserRun(),
    browserRun(),
    browserRun(),
    browserRun(),
    browserRun(),
  ])
})()
```

Comment: I don't use puppeter but multiple Chromium profiles can be launched using switch`--user-data-dir=path_to_another_profile` where `path_to_your_profile` is the absolute path of another profile passed to Chromium when launching it

Comment: Also the behavior that you mentioned of launching multiple instances of Chromium with multiple profiles is how the Chromium works. You cannot open multiple profiles from a single instance of Chromium

Comment: @Asesh this is the way I am launching new profiles now. I understand that chromium would create separate processes for new tabs though these are attached to the same app instance (?) when done manually. Task manager screenshots illustrate difference. If it wasn't for such large resource consumption I would not mind it at all.